# iPad Safari Web Inspector crashing on page load

Tags: ios, wordpress, ipad, safari, safari-web-inspector

I have a video focused website made in wordpress. When we go to test the website on iPad we connect it to a mac laptop and open the safari developer tools to check if we have any errors and whatnot. Everything works on our homepage but when we go to any video post we have added, it crashes the developer tools window, and the browser on the iPad has a little drop down at the top saying "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded".

The page is fine on the iPad, there aren't any PHP errors in our logs, everything works fine functionally, so I can't figure out what is crashing it.

Any ideas? Any way I can troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance :) And let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: I am having a similar issue with our WKWebView based app. Seems to be iOS 10 related. Just having Safari open on the connected dev machine causes the app to crash on any page load. "malloc: *** error for object 0x1700be360: pointer being freed was not allocated".

Comment: after I updated iOS to 10.0, I cannot debug on safari any more: I had to update itunes, then eventually maybe safari from 7.1, but then again maybe even whole OSX (10.9.5).  Issue still not solve - would like to avoid upgrading whole machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact problem and solved it by updating both OSX Safari and the iPad to the latest versions. Now i can use the Web Inspector again.

Comment: My iPad gen3 won't update anything newer than iOS 9.3.5. I used to be able to debug on OSX so it would seem that it is a OSX Safari/DevTools issue.