# On iOS 10, GLTF-WebGL app crashes, Application is build using WKWebView

Tags: javascript, webgl, ios10, wkwebview, gltf

I am working on 3D model in javascript & using GLTF webGL to render 3D model in iOS. I am loading this model using WKWebView in Ipad Air/Ipad Air 2.

This configuration/application works perfect in IOS9, But after upgrading OS to IOS 10 my application get crashed. I am trying to debug same on Xcode then showing following error message :

```
Error Message:  "#WK: Unable to acquire assertion for process 0".
```

We have tried same thing using UIWebView in IOS10 it is working but performance is low (application working slow).

Additional information :

1. GLTF-WEBGL link to open 3D model https://github.com/montagejs/glTF-webgl-viewer.git.
2. When I changed offsetHeight to scrollHeight, able to view the 3D model, but crashed after some time.

Any body have any cue to debug WebGL issues on iOS 10 ?

Comment: I just came upon the same problem, but I'm not using WebGL.  My client is using storyline SCORM content and having the same error.

Comment: Have you tried other glTF viewers?  It looks like that montagejs one dates back to glTF 0.8 in 2014.  There were breaking changes between glTF 0.8 and glTF 1.0.

Comment: Thank for replaying emackey,

Comment: I have tried with other glTF0.8 but still facing the same problem. Is this crashed issue is happened for height width properties.

Comment: Its not a WebGL issue, as this is not a WebGL error message.

Comment: Yes it's not a webGL Issue but 3D crashed due to webGL on WK webview @LJᛃ

Comment: Thxx all, i got the error why this 3d is crashing. Due to adding of texture. But i am unable resolve it.can anyone have the solution.

Comment: I encountered this error on our app using SDWebImage and WKWebView (no 3D). Setting SDImageCache's maxMemoryCountLimit fixed it. I think it's caused by GPU memory overflow.

Comment: How do you know you are  using SDWebImage? I am using meteor cordova to build an ios hybrid app and getting this exact error. I cannot find "SDImageCache" reference anywhere in the source code within xCode. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the log in console whether you can find anything.
I had the same error "Error Message:  "#WK: Unable to acquire assertion for process 0".", and I found it was because I used css property -webkit-overflow-scrolling, this property consumed a lot memory, and last WebKit process crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error, though I'm not using WebGL at all. I am, however, using [GPUImage2](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2).

Are you using the Safari Web Inspector on your host machine? Based on my experience and some [anecdotal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413723/ipad-safari-web-inspector-crashing-on-page-load#comment67720415_39413723) & [related](https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@cordova.apache.org/msg72842.html) [evidence](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7018), I think the problem is a bug in some combination of that and WKWebView on iOS 10.

It's not an ideal solution, but not using the web inspector has prevented  WKWebView from crashing for me.

(Interestingly, it doesn't crash if I use the web inspector but am not doing anything GPU intensive.)

Comment: can you elaborate on your response? When you say not using web inspector do you mean on the safari browser or enabling it on the ios mobile phone?

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling web inspector in safari and on the mobile phone did not solve the problem for me. However, I agree its an issue with the WKWebView and iOS10. I am using Meteor to build my iOS app and not using any SDWebImage or GPUImage2 as far as I know. I cannot find a reference to SDImage or SDWebImage.m anywhere in the generated source code. I read that setting SDImageCache.sharedImageCache (). MaxMemoryCountLimit = 100 will solve the issue with this error but I don't know where to set this value because I'm not using SDImageCache. Any help is much appreciated